# Dealing with &rest-parameters in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to define a function that accepts `&rest` parameters and delegates them to another function.

```
(html "blah" "foo" baz) => "<html>blahfoobaz</html>"
```

I did not find a better way than this one:

```
(defun html (&rest values)
  (concatenate 'string 
               "<html>" 
               (reduce #'(lambda (a b)
                           (concatenate 'string a b))
                       values :initial-value "") 
               "</html>"))
```

But this looks somewhat glumbsy to me, since line 4 does no more than concatenating the &rest parameter "values". I tried `(concatenate 'string "<html>" (values-list values) "</html>")` but this does not seem to work (SBCL). Could someone give me an advice?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun html (&rest values) 
  (apply #'concatenate 'string values))
```

Comment: Please note the question was changed after I gave this answer.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, it will not get much better, unless you use [`format`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/sec_22-3.html), but you can use the [CL-WHO](http://weitz.de/cl-who/) library, which lets you write HTML in Lisp:

```
(defun hello-page ()
  (with-html-output-to-string (string)
    (:html (:head (:title "Hello, world!"))
           (:body (:h3 "Hello, World!")
                  (:a :href "http://weitz.de/cl-who/"
                      "The CL-WHO library")))))
```

Edit:  The `format` way should perhaps also be shown:

```
(defun html (&rest values)
  (format nil "<html>~{~a~}</html>" values))
```